# Adding Additional Sidebar To Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add another sidebar to my Wordpress theme (Titan - http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/titan), but it seems to be a little more advanced than the themes being used in the tutorials.

I've been following this guide
http://www.blogohblog.com/adding-extra-sidebar-to-your-wordpress-theme/

My Functions.php looks like this

```
<?php
    locate_template( array( 'functions' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'titan-extend.php' ), true );
```

And the relevant block titan-extend.php file that I've been hacking away at looks like this

```
    /*---------------------------------------------------------
        6. Register Sidebars
    ------------------------------------------------------------ */
    function registerSidebars() {
        register_sidebar(array(
            'name' => __( 'Sidebar', 'titan' ),
            'id' => 'normal_sidebar',
            'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget' => '</li>',
            'before_title' => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
            'after_title' => '</h2>',
        ));
        register_sidebar(array(
            'name' => 'sidebar2'));
            'id' => 'sidebar2'
            'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget' => '</li>',
            'before_title' => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
            'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ));

    }
```

The current error I'm getting is
**Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Titan::registerSidebars() in /wp-content/themes/titan/functions/titan-extend.php on line 121**

That's all the info I have, any and all help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial your referring to is outdated and doesn't user WordPress best practices.

The proper way to register sidebar is to create a register function then hook it into `widgets_init`

in your functions.php file add this:

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'sydeberz_register_sidebar' );
function sydeberz_register_sidebar() {
 register_sidebar(
    array(
        'name' => 'sidebar2',
        'id' => 'sidebar2',
        'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</li>',
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
));

}
```

See Justin Tadlock's [Sidebars in WordPress](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/11/08/sidebars-in-wordpress) post.

Comment: That fixed the error, but I'm still not seeing the second side bar after I've included 

<?php get_sidebar( 'sidebar2' ); ?>

Into page.php and browsed a page

Comment: `<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar2' ); ?>`

Comment: Got it! Thanks @Chris_O , Any tips on aligning it to the other side now? Sidebar2.php contains
`<div id="sidebar2">

 <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar2' ); ?>

</div>`

And I've added this to my css file
` #sidebar2 {float:left;padding-bottom:30px;width:100px;} `

But it's not going anywhere...